# angular wrap jquery plugin how to handle many events

Tags: jquery, angular, jstree, angular-cli

I am making my first attempt at wrapping a jquery plugin, jstree, into an angular component.  My code is below.  I have the basic presentation working, but I am wondering what the best approach to wrapping the many events emitted by jstree would be.

I can just duplicate the the @output 'onSelection' emitter and have a lot of different event emitters (onLoaded, onReady, onLoadNode, etc), but wasn't sure if this was the right/idiomatic way of handling this.  Jstree has different arguments going to each event so not sure how I would handle a single emitter where different events would have different numbers of args or even if this is a reasonable approach.

Versions:     "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2", "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0", "jstree": "^3.3.3"

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'jstree';

@Component({
  selector: 'angular-jstree',
  templateUrl: 'angular-jstree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['angular-jstree.component.css'] ,
})
export class AngularJstreeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('jstree') element: ElementRef;

  @Input() jstreeData : Object = {};

  @Output()  onSelection: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter<Object>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    jQuery(this.element.nativeElement).jstree(this.jstreeData);

    jQuery(this.element.nativeElement).on("select_node.jstree", (node, selected, event) => {
      this.onSelection.emit({node: node, selected: selected, event: event});
    });
  }

}
```